# what is the meaning of a symbol $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$

Tags: algebraic-topology

what is the meaning of a symbol $\pi_1(X,x_0)=0$ when $X$ is a contractible space to $x_0$.

Actually I know that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is the fundamental group of $X$ based at $x_0$.But I could not understand how it could be $0$ as $0$ is a number and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is a set.

Comment: When $X$ is contractible, the group is trivial. So it is the group with one element $\{0\}$

Answer (score 2):

Often, "$0$" or "$1$" is used to represent the trivial group. The context here ($X$ contractible) pretty clearly indicates that's what "$\pi_1(X,x_0) = 0$" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2):

The group with only the identity is often referred to as the zero group, and (as an abuse of notation) often denoted by $0$, though it should be $\{0\}$.